# Create element in Dom using integer value

Tags: javascript

I have an Integer value that I need to create an element in the gift and then use it in a variable.

```js
var count = 5;
document.getElementById("lineCount").innerHTML = count;


var lineCount = document.getElementById("lineCount");
var recort1 = lineCount.replace('<div id="lineCount">', '');
var recort2 = recort1.replace('</div>', '');

console.log(recort2);
```

I need the value of the element saved in a variable I tried to use replace to cut the value of the tags, but it is not working.

Comment: its unclear what you want to achieve.Please be clear

Comment: I have an integer value in the count variable and I need that value in one element to then use it in another variable that is in another file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.textContent` to retrieve the text content of `div`s. No need to take the HTML string and remove HTML tags.

```js
let lineCount = document.getElementById('lineCount').textContent;

console.log(lineCount);
```

```html
<div id="lineCount">5</div>
```